# Weird error while running docker command "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker

I'm new with docker and I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
$ sudo docker pull ubuntu:13.10
$ sudo docker run ubuntu:13.10 echo "Hello World"
2014/04/21 20:17:12 no such file or directory
$ sudo docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
5f7495c94c0d        ubuntu:13.10        echo 'Hello world'   21 minutes ago      Exited (1) 21 minutes ago                       suspicious_ritchie
```

The problem is that the command didn't return what I was waiting for and not any other command works as expected...

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5):

It work for me "Linuxmint 17" after **install apparmor-utils only**.

I think that the correct issue reported around this problem is [#5135](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/5135)

I installed docker from official repositories of linummint 17 these are the oficial repositories of ubuntu 14.04

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue. Workaround: run docker with `-e=lxc`

```
docker -d --mtu=1460 --icc=false --dns=8.8.8.8 --dns=8.8.4.4 -b=bridge0 -e=lxc
```

More info https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/5191

I also had to do this, but it might not be needed in your case:

1. Install `apparmor-utils` if they aren't installed already.
2. Run `$ sudo aa-complain /usr/bin/lxc-start`

More info: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/2702